# creating my own exceptions c#

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

Following examples in my C# book and I came across a book example that doesn't work in Visual Studio. It deals with creating your own exceptions, this one in particular is to stop you from taking the square root of a negative number. But when I create the NegativeNumberException by using "throw new" I get an error that says "The type or namespace name 'NegativeNumberException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

How can I create my own exceptions if this isn't the right way? Maybe my book is outdated? Here's the code:

```
class SquareRootTest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool continueLoop = true;

        do
        {
            try
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a value to calculate the sqrt of: ");
                double inputValue = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                double result = SquareRoot(inputValue);

                Console.WriteLine("The sqrt of {0} is {1:F6)\n", inputValue, result);
                continueLoop = false;
            }
            catch (FormatException formatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + formatException.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a double value, doofus.\n");
            }
            catch (NegativeNumberException negativeNumberException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + negativeNumberException.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a non-negative value, doofus.\n");
            }
        } while (continueLoop);
    }//end main
    public static double SquareRoot(double value)
    {
        if (value < 0)
            throw new NegativeNumberException(
                "Square root of negative number not permitted.");
        else
            return Math.Sqrt(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to actually create the class "NegativeNumberException", which will derive from System.Exception. You can't just put class names there to create things.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`Exception` is just a *class* like many other classes in .Net. There're, IMHO, two tricky things with user defined exceptions:

1. Inherit your exception class from *Exception*, not from obsolete *ApplicationException*
2. User defined exception should have *many constructors* - **4** in the typical case

Something like that:

```
public class NegativeNumberException: Exception {
  /// <summary>
  /// Just create the exception
  /// </summary>
  public NegativeNumberException()
    : base() {
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Create the exception with description
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="message">Exception description</param>
  public NegativeNumberException(String message)
    : base(message) {
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Create the exception with description and inner cause
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="message">Exception description</param>
  /// <param name="innerException">Exception inner cause</param>
  public NegativeNumberException(String message, Exception innerException)
    : base(message, innerException) {
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Create the exception from serialized data.
  /// Usual scenario is when exception is occured somewhere on the remote workstation
  /// and we have to re-create/re-throw the exception on the local machine
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="info">Serialization info</param>
  /// <param name="context">Serialization context</param>
  protected NegativeNumberException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    : base(info, context) {
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason I had to change each `String` type to `string` or I got the error: `'String': static types cannot be used as parameters`.

Comment: @kill4silence: add `using System;` since `String` in an *alias* of `string` has been defined in the `System` namespace.

Comment: @JamesM This could be if you have a static class called String...maybe for Extension-methods.?

Answer (score 5):

All exceptions are types just like any other, and if you want to define a custom type of exception, you actually have to make a class for it:

```
/* You could also use ArgumentException, etc. */
class NegativeNumberException : Exception {
    …
}

…
```

Comment: [It's generally recommend to derive any custom exception types from `Exception`, and to specifically avoid `ApplicationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts(v=vs.110).aspx), but it this case I don't know why you wouldn't just throw the out of the box `ArgumentException`.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot: Huh, thanks. These best practices, always changing…

Answer (score 3):

Since .NET 3.0 custom exceptions [should be derived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from `Exception` and not `ApplicationException`, so use this:

```
public class NegativeNumberException : Exception
{ 
    public NegativeNumberException():base() { } 
    public NegativeNumberException (string message): base(message) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your custom Exception `NegativeNumberException`  class.

all custom Exception are child classes of Exception so derive `NegativeNumberException`  class from `Exception` class

From MSDN :

> If you are designing an application that needs to create its own
>   exceptions, you are advised to derive custom exceptions from the
>   Exception class. It was originally thought that custom exceptions
>   should derive from the ApplicationException class; however in practice
>   this has not been found to add significant value. For more
>   information, see Best Practices for Handling Exceptions.
>   ApplicationException uses the HRESULT COR_E_APPLICATION, which has the
>   value 0x80131600.

Try This:

```
 public class NegativeNumberException : Exception
        {         


           public NegativeNumberException():base()
            {


            }   

            public NegativeNumberException (string message): base(message)
            {


            }


        }
```