# What exception should be used when the value of a variable declared within a procedure is invalid?

Tags: c#, exception

I have a variable which I know will be invalid if it is zero, so would like to catch this situation. I started coding this as an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` but when I do this I get a blue squiggly line appearing under the first parameter for this exception type (paramName); as the variable I am referencing is not an argument of the procedure.

The value is being set from a call to a separate assembly (possibly not written by 'us', so am looking to handle the exception locally)

I've spent a while Googling, and looking at the options in intellisense, but can't see predefined exception that fits. Any suggestions for a better option than leaving as is or using the generic `Exception`?

Example of what I am doing for clarity:

```
    public long MyProcedure(long incomingVariable)
    {
        long eventId = ThirdParty.GetEventId(incomingVariable);

        if (eventId == 0)
        {
            eventId = ThirdParty.SecondaryCall();
        }

        if (eventId == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("eventId", "Event ID of zero");
        }
     }
```

Comment: Have you considered creating your own `Exception` class?

Comment: Actually no, didn't realise you could. Will have a look at that option.

Comment: It looks like`GetEventId` should be the one to throw an exception if it can't return a valid id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating my own exceptions c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391287/creating-my-own-exceptions-c-sharp)

Comment: @Lee - I should amend there actually, I simplified the code but GetEventId is going to a separate assembly that may be written by a third party. Will make an edit

Comment: You can do `throw new ArgumentException("No event found for incomingVariable " + incomingVariable, nameof(incomingVariable))`, because `incomingVariable` is what is invalid, not `eventId`.

Comment: Will `ThirdPart.GetEventId` only return 0 if the value of `incomingVariable` is invalid?

Comment: @lee- sorry the incomingVariable may be a bit of a red herring - I simplified the code but it actually makes a secondary call (will edit to show what I mean), but no incomingVariable can be valid and zero still returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`InvalidOperationException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.110).aspx) is the generic, catch all, "You've called a valid method, there's no specific issue with any particular parameters, but I'm not now in the correct state to actually function" exception.

> InvalidOperationException is used in cases when the failure to invoke a method is caused by reasons other than invalid arguments. Typically, it is thrown when the state of an object cannot support the method call.

Some framework classes further derive a more specific exception from `InvalidOperationException`, which you may want to consider doing if there's additional "structured" data you think would be useful for consumers. Also, worth paying attention to this:

> Because the InvalidOperationException exception can be thrown in a wide variety of circumstances, it is important to read the exception message returned by the [`Message`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.message(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Which is written from the consumers perspective - but I'd suggest that it should also be interpreted to say "make sure that any exception message *you* provide is specific and contains enough detail".