# Hanfire not logging custom exception with metadata

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, hangfire, coreclr

I have `asp.net core 2.1` application along with `HangFire 1.6.17`. HangFire is configured to execute a background job at certain interval.  The background job calls external API using HttpClient. If the http call fails, then the method throws custom exception with metadata. Idea is hangfire will log the exception with metadata. I followed [best-practices-for-exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions) to create exception

```
public class MyHttpRequestException : Exception
{
    public string Content { get; private set; }
    public string RequestUri { get; private set; }
    public string HttpResponse { get; private set; }

    public MyHttpRequestException()
    {
    }

    public MyHttpRequestException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }


    public MyHttpRequestException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException)
    {

    }

    public MyHttpRequestException(string message, string content, string httpResponse, string requestUri) 
        : base(message)
    {
        Content = content;
        RequestUri = requestUri;
        HttpResponse = httpResponse;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(base.ToString());
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendLine("Content");
        sb.AppendLine(Content);
        sb.AppendLine("RequestUri");
        sb.AppendLine(RequestUri);
        sb.AppendLine("HttpResponse");
        sb.AppendLine(this.HttpResponse);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

I also have extension method for `HttpResponseMessage` which ensures API request is successful, and if not throws `MyHttpRequestException`

```
public static class HttpResponseMessageExtensions
{
    public static async Task EnsureSuccessStatusCodeAsync(this HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return;
        }

        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        var httpResponse = response.ToString();
        var requestUri = response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString()
        if (response.Content != null)
            response.Content.Dispose();


        throw new MyHttpRequestException("Error while making http request.", content, httpResponse, requestUri);
    }
}
```

Here is my background Job which is invoked by Hangfire recurring job scheduler

```
public async Task DoSomething(string url)
{
    var response  = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url)
    await response.EnsureSuccessStatusCodeAsync();  

    // do something here if everything is okay  
}
```

**Issue**
    When `EnsureSuccessStatusCodeAsync` method throws `MyHttpRequestException` then Hangfire logs the exception as expected, and i see that in HangFire's dashboard. However Hangfire only logs Exception message and stack trace. ***I don't see my custom properties are being logged ( ie. Content, RequestUri, HttpResponse)***

In clssic .NET we use SerializationInfo like this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391287/creating-my-own-exceptions-c-sharp/20392944#20392944)
How do i create a custom exception in .NET Core so metadata will also get logged?

**Note:**
When the `MyHttpRequestException` gets thrown i noticed exception's ToString() method is getting called
    however, i dont see whatever ToString() returns is getting logged by Hangfire. 
    I dont know if this is hangfire issue, or i need to implement MyHttpRequestException is different way.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace that you see in Dashboard is formatted. You can see [here](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/129707d66fde24dc6379fb9d6b15fa0b8ca48605/src/Hangfire.Core/Dashboard/JobHistoryRenderer.cs#L187) and [here](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/129707d66fde24dc6379fb9d6b15fa0b8ca48605/src/Hangfire.Core/App_Packages/StackTraceFormatter/StackTraceFormatter.cs).

Because this custom stack trace format you can see your custom properties.

Comment: so whats the solution?