# Should custom exception classes derive from System.ApplicationException?

Tags: c#, exception

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.applicationexception?view=net-5.0 says that "ApplicationException Class" Serves as the base class for application-defined exceptions. But in an example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-user-defined-exceptions custom exception class derives from "Exception" base class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391287/creating-my-own-exceptions-c-sharp/20392944#20392944

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.applicationexception?view=net-5.0 "You **should derive custom exceptions** from the `Exception` class rather than the ApplicationException class. You should not throw an ApplicationException exception in your code, and you should not catch an ApplicationException exception unless you intend to re-throw the original exception."

Answer (score 1):

Well, [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.applicationexception?view=net-5.0) states clearly

> **Important**
>
> You should derive custom exceptions from the `Exception` class rather
> than the `ApplicationException` class. You should not throw an
> `ApplicationException` exception in your code, and you should not catch
> an `ApplicationException` exception unless you intend to re-throw the
> original exception.

So for custom exception we should use `Exception` as a base class

Comment: When i read i took application-defined exception and custom defined exception as same things. So what is application-defined exception.

Comment: Clowo: "It was originally thought that custom exceptions should derive from the `ApplicationException` class; however in practice this has not been found to add significant value." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685923/what-is-applicationexception-for-in-net

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, it doesn't matter.  If your exception type would be a better logical fit when derived from one of the system-provided exceptions, as a user I'd prefer that kind of implementation.  Think about what happens when user of your code catches the exceptions, and plan accordingly.